# How do I use datatable data in a variable for writing to a file?

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I'm grabbing some data off of webpages and trying to concatenate with some data pulled from other pages but keep getting the error that the data-tables need to be the same size. What am I missing here?
The datatables are myCoID (just a string) and NumStaff and NumClients- each of which has 1 row and 1 column. I've tried almost every permutation of

```
%myCoID + NumStaff + NumClients%
%myCoID + NumStaff[0] + NumClients[0]%
%[myCoID + NumStaff + NumClients]%
```

Where am I going wrong?